# Set display property on shadow dom button element

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yeLo8ck8/) describing this issue.  Given the html

```
<input type="file" name="geoFile" class="file-drop" >
```

which in turn generates the following shadow dom structure:

```
<input type="file" name="geoFile" class="file-drop">
    #shadow-root (user-agent)
        <input type="button" value="Choose File" pseudo="-webkit-file-upload-button">
            #shadow-root (user-agent)
                Choose File
        </input>
</input>
```

How can I set `display:none` to the button inside the first `shadow-root`?

I've tried

```
.file-drop {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 5px dashed darkgrey;

    input[type='button'] {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

but the button style is still showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't style the shadow DOM. You could obtain the same effect hiding the `input` and using a `label` with your stykles.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/elrumordelaluz/3s5L7bLs/1/) your fiddle forked working as explained before.

Comment: [An interesting article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) on how to style different `input[type=file]`

Answer (score 2):

To select the button, you could use the selector `.file-drop::-webkit-file-upload-button`.

Since you're using SASS, it would be:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b33cxogp/)

```
.file-drop {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 5px dashed darkgrey;

    &::-webkit-file-upload-button {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

As your question implies, this only applies to `-webkit` browsers since each browser has their own implementation.

Comment: This implies a limited support, since only in `webkit` browsers will be applied.